# Upload and Download file from iOS native app to server location

Tags: ios, http, networking

I want to upload and download some files (in particular audio files with .caf extension) from my iOS native app to a server (http) location. I have been provided with http folder path (http:...) by the server admin.

Since it's just for some feasibility analysis of another feature so can you please guide me with an easiest way to achieve read and write files from a server location? Or, is it necessary to write some server side code (web service) to make it happen?

FYI: I have a sample text file at server location and I'm able to read that file directly by using ASIHTTPRequest (see below - no web service used here - please excuse for specifying edited path). But I don't know how to upload files.

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://...Dispatcher/DispatcherTest.txt"];
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"responseString = %@", responseString);
}];

[request setFailedBlock:^ {
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
}];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why I'm voted down for my question. The server admin engineer gave me a server location (http path) and asked me to programmatically save and download the audio files there. As a front end app developer, I have asked a valid question. Based on the response, I could ask the admin to provide me a web service, instead of folder location at server. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASIHTTPRequest, you send a file using HTTP POST.  See "Sending a form POST with ASIFormDataRequest" in the docs.  However, ASIHTTPRequest is no longer under development.  You may want to pick a library that is being kept up to date.  I like MKNetworkKit.

Note that you have to have something on your server that is going to respond to POSTs and save the files somewhere, this doesn't just magically come for free.

Answer (score 0):

For store file on server use following code

```
-(void) Storeonserver
{

    NSUserDefaults *dflts=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *strURL = // your server address

   NSData *file1Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[recordedTmpFile path]];

//recordedTmpFile= your audio file path


    NSString *name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"abc.caf"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",name]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:file1Data]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
    NSLog(@"Return String= %@",returnString);
}
```

for download and play audio from server use following code

```
-(void) playAudio
{
//Play recoding from server
NSUrl *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourServerSideUrl/abc.caf"]
NSData *mydata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
AVAudioPlayer * avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:mydata error:nil];
[avPlayer prepareToPlay];
[avPlayer play];

}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by strURL (your server address)? All I have provided by server admin is a folder location at server (http://.../folder/).

Comment: I tried your solution but I can't see the file at server location.    
NSString *recordedTmpFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gw1" ofType:@"caf"];
    NSData *file1Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:recordedTmpFile];
I have my test audio (caf) file in app bundle so I used above code to specify the path.

I'm able to open the strURL path in browser so that can't be wrong.

Comment: And this is the output snippet of 'return string' at the end...
</HEAD><BODY><TABLE width=500 border=0 cellspacing=10><TR><TD>

<h1>The page cannot be displayed</h1>
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.
<hr>
<p>Please try the following:</p>
<ul>
<li>Contact the Web site administrator if you believe that this request should be allowed.</li>
<li>Make sure that the Web site address displayed in the address bar of your browser is spelled and formatted correctly. </li>
</ul>

Comment: what are you using at server side, asp.net or php???
i have return server side code in asp.net..

Comment: I think we have asp.net. My server admin told me it's windows (IIS) server. Can you share the code snippet?